# How to apply offset to fixed element (bottom: 0)

Tags: javascript

I am using the smooth scrollbar plugin and am having issues with elements with position fixed.
I have a div ID 'scroll', the nav, footer and content are inside this

Since transform creates a new local coordinate system(W3C Spec), position: fixed is fixed to the origin of scrollbar content container, i.e. the left: 0, top: 0 point.

Therefore, you may need to register a scroll listener and apply offsets to the fixed element.

I am having issues with the getting the footer (#footer) to work, the nav (#fixed) is working correctly

Any suggestions?

```
var fixedElem = document.getElementById('fixed');
var footerElem = document.getElementById('footer');

    var scrollbar = Scrollbar.init(
        document.getElementById('scroll'),
    );

scrollbar.addListener(function(status) {
    var offset = status.offset;

      fixed.style.top = offset.y + 'px';
      fixed.style.left = offset.x + 'px';
      footer.style.bottom = offset.y + 'px';
      footer.style.left = offset.x + 'px';
    });
```

CSS

```
#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0
  left: 0;
}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0
  left: 0;
}
```